# Shell scripting debug help - Iterating through files in a directory

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh
files = 'ls /myDir/myDir2/myDir3/'

for file in $files do
    echo $file
    java myProg $file /another/directory/    
done
```

What i'm trying to do is iterate through every file name under  /myDir/myDir2/myDir3/, then use that file name as the first argument in calling a java program (second argument is "/another/directory")

When I run this script: . myScript.sh

I get this error:
-bash: files: command not found

What did I do wrong in my script? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Neeaj's answer, strip off the whitespace from `files =`.

Better yet, use:

```
#!/bin/sh -f
dir=/myDir/MyDir2/MyDir3

for path in $dir/*; do
   file=$(basename $path)
   echo "$file"
   java myProg "$file" arg2 arg3
done
```

Bash is perfectly capable of expanding the `*` wildcard itself, without spawning a copy of `ls` to do the job for it!

EDIT: changed to call `basename` rather than `echo` to meet OP's (previously unstated) requirement that the path echoed be relative and not absolute.  If the cwd doesn't matter, then even better I'd go for:

```
#!/bin/sh -f
cd /myDir/MyDir2/MyDir3

for file in *; do
   echo "$file"
   java myProg "$file" arg2 arg3
done
```

and avoid the calls to `basename` altogether.

Comment: I want the basename $file to be an input to the java argument. Not just echo it.

Comment: How's the java program going to read the file without the full path?  If that's not a problem, you could just 'cd $dir' at the start of the script.

Comment: This could be improved using `printf '%s\n' "$file"` instead of the broken and deprecated echo. Then it will work with files named `-n`, `-e` etc and those containing spaces in a row. Don't forget to doublequote `$file` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

strip off the whitespace in and after `files =` as `files=RHS of assignment`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space surrounding the '=' : change

```
files = 'ls /myDir/myDir2/myDir3/'
```

into:

```
files='ls /myDir/myDir2/myDir3/'
```

and move the 'do' statement to its own line:

```
for file in $files
do
   ....
```

Comment: Did that.
Now the error is : syntax error near unexpected token 'echo'

Comment: Ok now the problem is, it echos the full path , not just the folder name by itself. I want "myFolder" to be echoed. Not "/myDir/Mydir2/myfolder"

Answer (score 0):

quote your variables and no need to use ls.

```
#!/bin/sh 
for file in /myDir/myDir2/* 
do
  java myProg "$file" /another/directory/    
done
```