# Bash -- How to execute syntax: ./myscript.sh *.dat?

Tags: bash

I would like to run recursively myscript.sh, to execute all files in the directory:

It has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810404/shell-scripting-debug-help-iterating-through-files-in-a-directory) that I could do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in * ; do
    echo $file
done
```

But I would like myscript.sh to execute with this syntax, so that I could select only certain filetypes to be executed:

./myscript.sh *.dat

Thus I modify the script above:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $1 ; do
    echo $file
done
```

In which when executing, it only executes first occurrence, not all files with *.dat extensions.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wildcard `*.dat` is expanded by the *shell* before your script ever sees it. So the filenames show up in your script as `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

You can work with them all at once by using the special `$@` variable:

```
for file in "$@"; do
    echo $file
done
```

Note that the double quotes around `"$@"` is special. From `man bash`:

```
@  Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When  the  expansion
   occurs  within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.  That
   is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...  If the double-quoted expansion occurs
   within  a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the begin-
   ning part of the original word, and the expansion of  the  last  parameter  is
   joined  with the last part of the original word.  When there are no positional
   parameters, "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).
```

Comment: +1. There is a bash shorthand: `for file; do ...; done` is equivalent to `for file in "$@"; do ...; done`

Answer (score -2):

You could do the same thing with just: `ls *.dat | xargs echo`

Comment: thanks @CodeGnome, good to know, but i guess its still safe as long as you know all your files in [a-z0-9], how about find? same problem?

Comment: You can use `find . -print0 | xargs -0` on some systems, but I'm not sure that syntax is portable. This tells `find` and `xargs` to separate with `'\0'` characters instead of whitespace, which solves the whole "spaces in filenames" issue. Now, if you've got a `'\0'` in your filename, I guess you're out of luck. ;-)

Comment: Yes, there are exceptions. And you can make it safer with the **--quote-name** and **--quoting-style** flags if your *ls* binary supports them.

Comment: There is no reason to write code that works in some or most cases when it is just as easy to write code that works in all cases.

Answer (score -2):

You need to get the actual contents of *, like so:

```
for file in $* ; do
 echo $file 
done
```

Comment: Welcome to S/O - this answer was probably downvoted because of [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) errors, and because you have the wrong idea about what `$*` (or `*`) does (or simply misunderstood the question). The former is a type of parameter expansion, and the latter is a glob expansion, which was intentional.

Comment: What do you mean "quoting errors" -- the code is 1 character different from the original code and does exactly the same thing as the code posted in other answers.

Comment: One was in the original code and not directly relevant (`echo "$file"`). The other depends what you mean by "get the contents of `*`" - this sentence makes it sound like you have mixed up ideas about globs and expansions... If what you actually meant was to "pass a pattern to the script by escaping it correctly when invoked, then expand the pattern(s) in the parameter named `*` using `$*`" (odd choice), then you can ignore my previous comment. Since you never mentioned the real problem (escaping the pattern) it doesn't sound like that's what you meant.

Comment: @mcdigman - its one character different from an incorrect sample of code. Your one character change does not make it correct.